# error connection timeout when getting size of image

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a some youtube video ids and storing them in an array then I looped on each video id to determine the size of that id's thumbnail. The process im using works until `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` happens. This error happens on different loop indexs so the problem is not with inputting a broken url. How can I get all the thumbnail size without having timeout error. Thanks in advance.

**note:** the process works to a certain random video id then error happens.

[image]

```js
const url = require('url')
const http = require('http')
const sizeOf = require('image-size')

//example array
const myArr = ['ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw', 'ficzsusamA0Mw'......]

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  const imgUrl = `http://img.youtube.com/vi/${myArr[i}/maxresdefault.jpg`
  const options = url.parse(imgUrl)

  http.get(options, function(response) {
    const chunks = []
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk)
    }).on('end', function() {
      const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
      if (sizeOf(buffer).width == 120 && sizeOf(buffer).height == 90) {
        console.log(`{"video_thumbnail": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/${myArr[i]}/hqdefault.jpg"}`)
      } else {
        console.log(`{"video_thumbnail": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/${myArr[i]}/maxresdefault.jpg"}`)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: the error seems like you get no response in the first place and your error handling is for a response.. try listening for an error from `http.get` itself